# React pagination through data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issues with my paging on my react application. Everytime I click next, the state will go from account[20] to having accounts[40]. I have set a loadData function in the root of my app so when the user clicks next it will update the state. Example:

```
loadData: function(pageNumber) {
        this.state.accounts = null;
        this.setState({
            accounts: this.getFlux().actions.loadAccounts(pageNumber)
        });
    },
```

So each time it increments it will get the next 20 or previous 20 records from the API.

The way I've set my records up is like this:

Database React Component render section:

```
 return (
                <div className='container'>
                    <h1 className='data-table__title'>Database</h1>
                <table className='data-table'>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr className='data-table__row--top'>
                        {columnTitles.map(this.renderTitles)}
                    </tr>



         {loading ? this.renderLoading() : accounts.map(this.renderAccounts)}

                {this.renderLoading}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Pagination updateData={this.props.loadData} totalPages={totalPages}/>
        </div>
    );
```

Which will call this function within it

```
renderAccounts : function (accounts, index) {
        return (
            <AccountsTable data={accounts}/>
        );
    },
```

The AccountTable component just loops out components with an object of data foreach component.

How do I clear the old stuff and replace it with new records every time I click next or previous?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by the Flux store itself not being cleared when you request a new page. Here are some options:

- Clear the store when it receives the `loadAccounts` action.
- Return only the accounts for the requested page in your `loadAccounts` action creator. For example, your accounts could have a `page` property, and you could `filter` it.

It may be that your `loadAccounts` action creator simply returns the wrong data. I would look there and see what it's returning.

By the way, this line of code:

```
this.state.accounts = null;
```

is not necessary and is actually a bad idea. You should always use `setState` when you wish to change state, and never mutate `this.state` directly. In any case, your subsequent `setState` call would override it even if it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was working on it with another developer this morning who understood stores more than I did and he sorted that part for me. It works a treat now cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which flux you are using but the pattern should be button click for next page calls clickHandler which calls nextPage action which has a listener in the store which sets the currentPage data and triggers event which component listens to and fetches currentPage data and then setState.